# MultiOutputRegressor Dataset Preparation

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

if I am using the MultiOutputRegressor in sklearn, should I remove the target variables y1, y2, ..., yn from the Dataset X so that in using X_train and X_test those target variables are not in the training dataset leading to an incorrect model?

lets assume my data has 100 columns and 1000 samples I want to predict y as columns Index 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99 how should I go about y and X variables? call the dataset 'dataset'

is it

```
X = np.delete(dataset, [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99], axis=1)  
y = dataset[:, [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99]]
```

or does MultiOutputRegressor automatically drop the target feature column from the X dataset as it loops over them for training?

If I train to predict a singular y using a normal regressor like Stacking Regressor w/ base and final estimators; and remove that feature from X, I get decent r2 scores of around 0.87 for 1000 samples and 54 features, but then I need to put my whole code inside a loop that moves across the prediction variables and that takes exponential time as predictions and dataset size/features increase

if I use the same stacking regressor but wrap it inside a MultiOutputRegressor and drop all prediction targets from X I get weirdly bad results like an r2 score of -0.1 no matter the sample size which makes me think that I shouldn't be removing them..

Answer (score -1):

> should I remove the target variables y1, y2, ..., yn from the Dataset X

yes, otherwise you'll have y1 available to use to predict y1, etc. (You can give it a try: you should get perfect scores, depending on your model flavor.)

> or does MultiOutputRegressor automatically drop the target feature column from the X dataset as it loops over them for training?

No, it doesn't work that way. You can see [here in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d6e0a3e8ddf92a7e5561245224dab102/sklearn/multioutput.py#L273) that it passes the whole of `X` to each regression problem.

> If I train to predict a singular y [...] and remove that feature from X, I get decent r2 scores of around 0.87 [... but] if I use the same [model] but wrap it inside a MultiOutputRegressor and drop all prediction targets from X I get weirdly bad results like an r2 score of -0.1 [...]

This suggests to me that some of the targets are very useful in predicting some of the others; check some feature importance measure(s) to see.  (I suppose it's also possible that one or more targets aside from y1 are just really hard to predict.)
You may be interested in the `RegressorChain` meta-model, which iteratively predicts the targets, incorporating the previous ones.

Comment: So thank you so much for this answer 
I have a question about how do I go about dropping each column in a regressor chain? I drop all of them from X before starting any model training
 
Also using the MOR this is what is weird
if I leave the columns, I don't get perfect scores (I did that mistake in an early build and got 0.999999 r2 score). but I get around ~0.85-87 r2 depending on sample size

Comment: In the chain you should still drop them all from X.  For the performance when includinf them, are those test scores? Maybe the model was getting perfect training performance through other features and didn't pick the yi=yi solution.

Comment: early build referred to was sample test with single Lin Reg on 1 target using whole dataset. when I forgot to drop target from X I got r2 0.9999 

progressed until build operated on a single target, and loops over all targets using a loop on top wrapping whole model. loop avgs 0.87-0.88 r2 score (1000 sample dataset x 54 features)

if I rewrite using MultiOutput or RegChain and remove all y targets the scores degrade severely. 
if I leave them I get r2 score max 0.94-0.95. imo makes sense bc multiout fits model per target and avgs preds. ys doesn't affect it, drop them destroys features